# sum $o_p(1)$ $n$ times

Tags: probability

I wonder that what $o_p(1)$ $n$ times would result in, where $n$ is the sample size.

For that matter, I am also curious if 
$$1/n \sum_{i=1}^n o_p(1) = o_p(1)~\text{or}~o_p(1/n). $$

Comment: Please clarify what your notation refers to

Comment: There are many possible interpretations of this question: please explain the context and the meaning of your notation.